# How to override standard ActionBar function?

Tags: android, eclipse, overriding, android-actionbar

I would like to override standard ActionBar in order to do some checking before going to previous activity. I would like to check if there is something entered into editText and if it is, I want to ask whether to go back no matter something is entered or stay in this window. I just want to knwo where to put if else loop.

This is in onCreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

And two methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activityB, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place for a reaction on a user input is `onOptionsItemSelected`. In the case block of the desired item of the ActionBar, you can check with `if(EditText.getText() != null)` if something was typed in or not.

Edit:

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if(yourEditText.getText() != null){
            // ask user what to do
        } else {
            // nothing was typed -> move to home activity
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: can you edit your answer to write me a full onOptionsItemSelected method?

Comment: Done. Keep in mind that maybe you have to redesign this. Because you wanna give the user the choice what to do you'll use a `Dialog` or something like that.